# Dynamically Insert/Update Item in DynamoDB With Python Lambda using event['body']

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am working on a lambda function that gets called from API Gateway and updates information in dynamoDB. I have half of this working really dynamically, and im a little stuck on updating. Here is what im working with:

dynamoDB table with a partition key of **guild_id**

My dummy json code im using:

```json
{
  "guild_id": "126",
  "guild_name": "Posted Guild",
  "guild_premium": "true",
  "guild_prefix": "z!"
}
```

Finally the lambda code:

```py
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    table = client.Table("guildtable")
    itemData = json.loads(event['body'])
    
    guild = table.get_item(Key={'guild_id':itemData['guild_id']})
    
    #If Guild Exists, update
    if 'Item' in guild:
      table.update_item(Key=itemData)
      
      responseObject = {}
      responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
      responseObject['headers'] = {}
      responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      responseObject['body'] = json.dumps('Updated Guild!')
      
      return responseObject
    
    #New Guild, Insert Guild
    table.put_item(Item=itemData)
    
    responseObject = {}
    responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
    responseObject['headers'] = {}
    responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    responseObject['body'] = json.dumps('Inserted Guild!')
      
    return responseObject
```

The insert part is working wonderfully, How would I accomplish a similar approach with update item? Im wanting this to be as dynamic as possible so I can throw any json code (within reason) at it and it stores it in the database. I am wanting my update method to take into account adding fields down the road and handling those

I get the follow error:

```
Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema.
```

Comment: Its not clear what is the issue with your current code? Any errors? What exactly is wrong with the code?

Comment: @Marcin Sure thing sorry about that. Here is the error im getting when it runs the update portion of the code:

`code`
Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema.
`code`

Comment: Please update the question with the full error msg. Also what is the schema of your table? The error is about the schema, yet you haven't provided it.

Comment: The schema is exactly what im inserting the first time I execute this code, 

primary key: guild_id
guild_name
guild_prefix
guild_premium

Comment: This schema could change though if I insert something else, the inserting is working great and inserts the json code I provided. Now im trying to call this endpoint again and since it already exists, it runs update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *"The provided key element does not match the schema"* error means something is wrong with `Key` (= primary key). Your schema's primary key is `guild_id: string`.  Non-key attributes belong in the `AttributeUpdate` parameter.  See the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.update_item).

Your `itemdata` appears to include non-key attributes. Also ensure `guild_id` is a  string `"123"` and not a number type `123`.

```py
goodKey={"guild_id": "123"}

table.update_item(Key=goodKey, UpdateExpression="SET ...")
```

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html#GettingStarted.Python.03.03) have a full `update_item` example.

Comment: I see, so doing my approach I would need to extract guild_id from the json I am getting, then remove this entry from that same json and then use that for attribute updates?

Comment: @SamuelHeinicke  Yes.  Set the new values in an `UpdateExpression` string, with value substitutions provided in `ExpressionAttributeValues` (`AttibuteUpdates` is deprecated, see edits).  The DynamoDB developer guide has a full [update_item example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html#GettingStarted.Python.03.03).